# how to validate mobile number using ng-pattern directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to validate mobile number field using ng-pattern directive. I want that the field data should be numeric only and exact of 10 digits. 
Please help me to achieve this. Thanx in advance..

Html Code

```
Mobile Number :
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mobileNo" name="mobileNo" />
```

Comment: `<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mobileNo" name="mobileNo" data-ng-pattern="/^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/" />`

Comment: Adding to @Vineet's comment . you will get error formName.mobileNo.$error.pattern. you can use this flag to any html tag example as below <p ng-show="userForm.mobileNo.$error.pattern" class="help-block" >Enter valid mobile number</p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regular expression to achieve this.

try this one

Html

```
Mobile Number :
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mobileNo" name="mobileNo" ng-pattern="regEx" />
```

JS

```
$scope.regEx="/^[0-9]{10,10}$/;"
```

See example of ng-pattern     http://learnit.visrosoftware.com/try/O8qvHguV

Answer (score -1):

This could be simplest one

```
ng-pattern="/^\d{10,15}$/"
```